# Why can't I override a method that takes a value-class as parameter in Scala?

Tags: scala, overriding, value-class

I'm playing around with value classes (class that extends AnyVal) in Scala 2.10.3 but are running into a strange compiler error when using them as parameter to abstract methods.
As the following example demonstrates:

```
class ValueClass(val x: Int) extends AnyVal

trait Test {
  def foo(v: ValueClass): Int
}

new Test {
  override def foo(v: ValueClass): Int = 1
}
```

The compiler spits out the following error:

```
error: bridge generated for member method foo: (v: ValueClass)Int in anonymous class $anon
which overrides method foo: (v: ValueClass)Int in trait Test
clashes with definition of the member itself;
both have erased type (v: Int)Int
          override def foo(v: ValueClass): Int = 1
```

Why doesn't this work? And is there a way to pass a value class into an abstract method?

Comment: Upgrade to the latest stable Scala version, whish is 2.11.1 right now. Your snippets work there.

Comment: Compiles in Scala 2.10.4 REPL, too.

Comment: FYI, I got the same error with Scala REPL 2.10.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as others noted, this issue has been fixed in later versions. If you are curious at all as to what was changed, I suggest you take a look into this [pull request](https://github.com/retronym/scala/commit/9f142b114be1261f55ea82b9cd1f9d9f91b3cad6).

> SI-6260 Avoid double-def error with lambdas over value classes Post-erasure of value classs in method signatures to the underlying
>   type wreaks havoc when the erased signature overlaps with the generic
>   signature from an overriden method. There just isn't room for both.
>   But we *really* need both; callers to the interface method will be
>   passing boxed values that the bridge needs to unbox and pass to the
>   specific method that accepts unboxed values.
>
> This most commonly turns up with value classes that erase to Object
>   that are used as the parameter or the return type of an anonymous
>   function.
>
> This was thought to have been intractable, unless we chose a different
>   name for the unboxed, specific method in the subclass. But that sounds
>   like a big task that would require call-site rewriting, ala
>   specialization.
>
> But there is an important special case in which we don't need to
>   rewrite call sites. If the class defining the method is anonymous,
>   there is actually no need for the unboxed method; it will *only* ever
>   be called via the generic method.
>
> I came to this realisation when looking at how Java 8 lambdas are
>   handled. I was expecting bridge methods, but found none. The lambda
>   body is placed directly in a method exactly matching the generic
>   signature.
>
> This commit detects the clash between bridge and target, and recovers
>   for anonymous classes by mangling the name of the target method's
>   symbol. This is used as the bytecode name. The generic bridge forward
>   to that, as before, with the requisite box/unbox operations.